# Ignore rows if the criteria are not met either in SQL/Python

Tags: python, sql

I have two tables, first one is a list of customers that is browsing/checking in the website, and second one is list of members and actual transactions that they made.

I am trying to see for every check that they done, what are the total transactions from that day to the next 30 days. But I want to ignore the checks after the initial point if its within 30 days, I will include it if > 30 days.

I have tried in SQL adding additional column (if next date-current date < 30 then 0) and also using row number, but unsure what is the next steps. But this is will roll over and the final step is just need to exclude the check date if its < 30 days, so my total cost would be accurate.

Thanks

[This is sample table]

[image: 1]

[Result that I am aiming for]

[image: 2]